# Keep variables including spaces when calling command in bash script

Tags: arrays, bash, quoting

In a script such as this

```
#! /bin/bash -i
arguments=(arg1 "arg2 has many spaces")
echo arguments count = ${#arguments[@]}
echo arguments = ${arguments[@]}
echo ls ${arguments[@]}
ls ${arguments[@]}
```

How can I keep `arg2` as a single argument to `ls`?

This is the actual output:

```
arguments count = 2
arguments = arg1 arg2 has many spaces
ls arg1 arg2 has many spaces
ls: arg1: No such file or directory
ls: arg2: No such file or directory
ls: has: No such file or directory
ls: many: No such file or directory
ls: spaces: No such file or directory
```

This shows that `arguments` initially has 2 elements but when it is used as arguments in the `ls` command the quotes are no longer there (obviously, since they were remove already when `arguments` was initialized) so `ls` sees 5 arguments.

How can I apply quoting to each of the array elements separately in order to give `ls` two arguments by keeping the second element together?

(In the real case I don't know the actual content of the array and `ls` is only an example which illustrates the problem.)

Comment: ```ls "${arguments[@]}"```

Comment: Sometimes it is really hard to search for things. If my duplicate question makes it more likely that someone can find an answer to their searches, I'm happy.